# Typo3 Define storagePid for CommandController command

Tags: typo3, scheduler, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I would like to import different data using a CommandController (scheduler).
I allready figured out that it is possible to set a global storagePid like:

```
module.tx_myextension.persistence.storagePid = 123
```

source: https://worksonmymachine.org/blog/commandcontroller-and-storagepid

That works fine, but my extension contains multiple models which should be saved on different Pid's

I also found an old post where someone said it is possible to define a pid for each model which would be exactly what I need:

```
module.tx_myextension.persistence.classes.tx_myextension_domain_model_player.storagePid = 124
module.tx_myextension.persistence.classes.tx_myextension_domain_model_customer.storagePid = 125
```

source: https://typo3-german.typo3.narkive.com/WxjjtxXa/scheduler-storage-pid

But it seems like this lines get ignored. Is this the correct way or do I do something wrong?

I am on TYPO3 6.2.44

Comment: Try to define the uids as comma separated list, does that work?

That should work for retrieval at least, not sure about storing.

Do you only wanna retrieve those models, or also store new models?

Comment: I need to do both, retrieve and store them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to create params for the controller action. For each model a storage pid.

so you have `myCommand($domain1Pid, $domain2Pid,$domain3Pid, ...)`

Now as first call in your function you get the querySettings for the repositories and apply the storage pids:

```
$querySettings = $this->domain1Repository->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
$querySettings->setStoragePageIds([$domain1Pid]);
$this->domain1Repository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
```

repeat this for each repository. In the scheduler job settings or cli you can now define the pids for each storage.

btw: you can also use `$domain->setPid(123)` to set the pid of each model where to save.